# Condition with linked tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a report from my MySQL database.

I have 2 tables:

___Rooms

```
|--------|------------|
| ROO_Id | ROO_Number |
|--------|------------|
| 1      | 101        |
| 2      | 102        |
| 3      | 103        |
| 4      | 104        |
| 5      | 105        |
|--------|------------|
```

___Bookings

```
|--------|------------|------------|------------|-------------------|
| BOO_Id | BOO_RoomId | BOO_DateCI | BOO_DateCO | BOO_ArrivalStatus |
|--------|------------|------------|------------|-------------------|
| 1      | 1          | 2018-07-03 | 2018-07-05 | checkout          |
| 2      | 2          | 2018-07-16 | 2018-07-17 | checkin           |
| 3      | 3          | 2018-07-14 | 2018-07-16 | none              | 
| 4      | 5          | 2018-07-14 | 2018-07-18 | checkin           | 
|--------|------------|------------|------------|-------------------|
```

---

My goal is to have the following report:

> The date of the report is today : `2018-07-16`.

```
|------------|----------------|
| ROO_Number | BOO_LiveStatus |
|------------|----------------|
| 101        | no             |
| 102        | in-house       |
| 103        | in-house       |
| 104        | no             |
| 105        | in-house       |
|------------|----------------|
```

---

I put a SQLFidde here :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bb474

---

My last try was this one:

```
SELECT 
    ROO_Number, 
    IF(BOO_DateCI >= '2018-07-16' AND BOO_DateCO <= '2018-07-16', 'in-house', 'no')
        AS BOO_LiveStatus
FROM ___Rooms
INNER JOIN ___Bookings
    ON ___Rooms.ROO_id = ___Bookings.BOO_RoomId
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have put the `<` and `>` conditions in the wrong place. Also, you need to use the `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. Please see the corrected query below:

```
SELECT 
    ROO_Number, 
    IF(BOO_DateCI <= '2018-07-16' AND BOO_DateCO >= '2018-07-16', 'in-house', 'no')
        AS BOO_LiveStatus
FROM ___Rooms
LEFT JOIN ___Bookings
    ON ___Rooms.ROO_id = ___Bookings.BOO_RoomId
ORDER BY 
  ROO_Number
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/890685/3/0)

Comment: Hello, it looks working but not when I have 2 consecutive bookings for the same room: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01b9ed/1. Do you know why? Thanks for your help.